# Filtering a repeating table linked to a secondary datasource

Tags: infopath2010

I have an infopath form based on a sharepoint list (worktracker).

In that form there is a repeating section which holds data from a secondary source which is the worktracker list again.

I would like to filter that table using the value in a field on the form - this enables me to run a check on duplicate items on the list by using a calculated checking reference.

I have done this by using conditional formatting to hide the non-matching items but that this killing my form as IE throws tantrum as it takes too long.

Does anyone know another way to do this?  I am stuck using IE8 - not my choice!

UPDATE:

So since posting the above, I had since tried using a REST connection which doesn't work as my list is too big.  I have also tried using an XML connection to a filtered view and that didn't work either!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form, select the value field. Create a rule that sets the secondary data source's **query field** of the same name to that value. Then query the secondary data source. It will only return the items where the value matches.